# Ceph iSCSI network deployment

Tags: ceph, iscsi

I intend to install ceph cluster with iSCSI gateways. Was wondering, about networking of ceph iSCSI gateways, typically the following:

1. iSCSI gateways should have a separate (Public)network and private
   network, i.e. Public to connect to iSCSI clients and private to
   connect to ceph public network?
2. If 1 is true, how does colocated iscsi gateway work? does it use ceph public network for both iscsi public network and iscsi backend network to connect to ceph?
3. What is better-

- Having two dedicated Networks for iscsi clients & a separate backend network to connect to ceph public? (As iscsi gateway would be a ceph client as well, or?)
- Having one aggregated public network for iscsi clients & a separate backend network to connect to ceph public?

Comment: Basically, iSCSI gateways in ceph are to provide rbd access to clients. If your clients are allowed to connect to ceph directly via ceph public network you probably don't need a gateway. If this is not the case and you actually need a gateway then it makes sense to split the network traffic as you describe in 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. There are some clients not compliant/do not understand rbd directly, but they do understand iscsi. Iscsi gateways can help in those cases,like with windows clients or ovirt like engines which support iscsi but not ceph rbd directly. In that case, no separate network for iscsi gateways is needed.

It will be an overhead component sitting on top of ceph, just to enable non-compatible clients to consume ceph storage indirectly.